# Is it possible to create multiple Chrome Hosted Apps for the same domain?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

[Our product](https://paydirtapp.com) has both a free component, and a full featured, subscription based web application. I've created a Chrome Hosted App - essentially an installable bookmark - for each both of those parts of our product.

The interesting parts of the app [manifests](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest) are as follow:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"app": {
    "launch": {
          "container": "tab",
          "web_url": "https://paydirtapp.com/dashboard"
    }
}
```

---

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"app": {
    "launch": {
          "container": "tab",
          "web_url": "https://paydirtapp.com/free_invoice_creator"
    }
}
```

---

I can install the [free invoice creator app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-invoice-maker/pegffgjpaihmoiajljeclicmckcnagig), and [the full featured app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paydirt-time-tracking-and/gfdhdljacjbjheinggpijfnmmpkpdkmj), but not both at the same time.

Attempting to do so (in Chrome 26.0.1410.10 (Official Build 183151) dev) causes the following error message:

"An error has occurred. Could not add the application because it conflicts with "Free Invoice Maker".

The only reference I can find to this issue is in https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest, where they state the following:

---

Important: If you provide multiple apps, avoid overlapping URLs. If a user tries to install an app whose "web_url" or "urls" values overlap with those of an already installed app, the second installation will fail due to URL conflict errors. For example, an app that specifies a "urls" value of "http://mail.example.com/" would conflict with an app that specifies "http://mail.example.com/mail/".

---

Previously, my `web_url` value was just set to `https://paydirtapp.com/`, which caused the same error. I expected that updating it so that it wasn't a substring of the other app would solve the problem, but it hasn't.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have multiple Chrome Hosted Apps where the `web_url` is for the same domain?

Comment: Using separate subdomains for each app should work.  For example, use `https://dashboard.paydirtapp.com` and `https://free_invoice_creator.paydirtapp.com`.  You will likely need a new SSL certificate that contains both of those names.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Moshe Matz (copy from comment):

Using separate subdomains for each app should work. 
For example, use https://dashboard.paydirtapp.com and https://free_invoice_creator.paydirtapp.com. You will likely need a new SSL certificate that contains both of those names.

Comment: "Does anyone know if it's possible to have multiple Chrome Hosted Apps where the web_url is for the *same* domain?"

Answer (score 0):

Separate subdomains should work. We don't currently have a solution for the same domain case.